# why is getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments

From `OverlayActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overlay);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first chatRootFragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.video_player_fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment mMessageListFragment = new FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment();

        if (mMessageListFragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.video_player_fragment_container, mMessageListFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            Log.e("OverlayActivity", "Error in creating chatRootFragment");
        }
    }

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment fragment = (FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay_id);//<= NULL
    OverlayActivity.super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The frgment:

```
public class FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK, getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("USER_DATA_EXTRA", "Yo User"));
    super.onDestroy();
    playlistManager.invokeStop();
    exitFullscreen();
}
}
```

fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_play_activity_video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:useDefaultControls="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_overlay.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/video_player_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML of the Activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay_id
```

is the id of your `RelativeLayout`.
From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)):

> findFragmentById
>
> Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction. This first searches through fragments that are currently added to the manager's activity; if no such fragment is found, then all fragments currently on the back stack associated with this ID are searched.

This means that either your `fragment` is inflated from XML - in which case you will have to use the id of your `<Fragment>` element if any - or to the container with the given ID that hosts the fragment.

If you added your fragment using a transaction and you need to retrieve it later then use `findFragmentByTag (String tag)` and add the fragment using [add](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

```
 add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

Comment: I tried with fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay as well as fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay_id

Comment: If you try with R.id.video_player_fragment_container once the fragment is added you will find it. 
The id either refers to a <fragment> tag or to the container the fragment is added.

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I should use

```
    FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment fragment = (FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id. video_player_fragment_container);
```

instead of

```
    FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment fragment = (FullScreenVideoPlayerUnderlayFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_full_screen_video_player_underlay_id);//<= NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding fragment what I should do is I would add a frame layout in `activity_main.xml` and i made a  function to load a fragment in that frame layout here's a function.

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutId, fragment, title);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

This worked for me very good I hope same for you... 
happy coding. :)